# How can I store key presses into variables to refactor this code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio, addeventlistener

I'm trying to build a simple piano so a keypress plays the corresponding sound. I have data attributes set up in my html and on the audio elements like so:

```
<div class="piano-keys">
      <div data-key="65" class="wkey" id="key"></div>
        <div data-key="81" class="bkey" id="key></div>
</div>

<audio id="65" data-key="65" src="notes/261-C.mp3"></audio>
<audio id="83" data-key="83" src="notes/293-D.mp3"></audio>
```

and my jquery is as follows:

```
 $(document).keyup(function(e){
         if(e.keyCode == 65){
             var c = document.getElementById('65');
             c.play();
             c.currentTime = 0;
      } else if(e.keyCode == 83){
            var c = document.getElementById('83');
             cSharp.play();
             cSharp.currentTime = 0;
       }
    });
```

This obviously works but I will need 25 if/else and I know it can be done a lot cleaner. Instead of having to target the individual ID's. I tried to create variables for they key presses like this:

```
var key = $('.key[data-key="${e.keyCode}"]');
```

but that obviously never worked. I'm new to jquery if that hasn't become painfully obvious by the stage.

Comment: Are you checking the keyCode to make sure it is a key associated with one of your audio?

Comment: ID means unique, class means multiple - refactor your IDs and classes. - You're also missing a `"` in `id="key`

Comment: Also, is a keyup appropriate for playing a piano?

Comment: keyup was used because during testing I was not getting the correct keycode with keypress.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you can't have the same ID multiple times on one page, other than that you can just do something like this

```
$(document).keyup(function(e){
    var key = e.which;
    var note =document.getElementById(key);
    note.play();
    note.currentTime = 0;


})
```

it will play the corresponding audio to which ever key is pressed. I'm not sure what you are doing with `currentTime` but you didn't mention it in your question, so this need adapting to do whatever it is that you are doing with that.

Comment: currentTime is needed to reset the audio if it is immediately pressed again. Otherwise the note will continue playing.

Answer (score -2):

You cannot repeat id attributes in HTML

So, the solution is:

```
<div class="piano-keys">
      <div data-key="65" class="wkey key"></div>
        <div data-key="81" class="bkey key"></div>
</div>
```

And this line also have an error, you haven't a "65" id

```
var c = document.getElementById('65');
```

Maybe jQuery selectors will be usefull to you, to find the data-key in your html

Comment: This doesn't answer the OPs question